# Uncaught Modal is not a function - apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, apex-code

I'm new at Apex and trying to understand APEX System. When I try to implement Tree View code block there is an error about Modal Dialog Error;

```
$("#t_TreeNav").treeView("option", "tooltip", {
  
    content: function(cb, node, ) {
        
        return node.label;
 
    }
} );

$("#t_TreeNav").tooltip("option", "items", ".a-TreeView-content");
```

**Error:**

```
desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeView is not a function
    at Object.javascriptFunction (favoriler?session=6128032290639&dialogCs=TEsgfXkqPJSXNJzM-Y0RWOoIxg6mukkH0ISPGeIBn1hbWuAR7fARYWRzUdku2Y9zuwFASfunIo-N3lktASDdZQ:331)
    at Object.da.doAction (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:21)
    at Object.da.doActions (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:21)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:21)
    at Function.each (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:2)
    at Object.da.actions (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:21)
    at Function.each (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (desktop_all.min.js?v=20.1.0.00.13:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding `" $(document).ready(function() "` it turned out to another uncaught statement which is ;

ERROR;

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeView is not a function
     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (.....?
 
 VM4586:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: customEvent is not defined
     at close (<anonymous>:1:318)
```

Adding if statement it worked better.

```
 if (node.label != 'ID_MENU') {
             return node.label; }
```

Comment: still there is an error but at least it's working..

Comment: up.. Still there is no solution for that even there is 20.2 apex new version